# Why the output is changed when using case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can anyone explain the Result?

```
DECLARE @dec AS VARCHAR(5)

SET @dec = 'Yes'

DECLARE @val DECIMAL(15, 2);

SET @val = - 34152542256.86;

SELECT @val as c1
    ,CAST(@val AS BIGINT) as c2

SELECT @val as c1
    ,CASE @dec
        WHEN 'Yes'
            THEN CAST(@val AS BIGINT)
        ELSE @val
        END as c2
```

Results:

of first select statement:

```
 c1                     c2
-34152542256.86         -34152542256
```

of second select statement:

```
 c1                     c2
-34152542256.86         -34152542256.00
```

Comment: The CASE must return a datatype able to store the different operands: @val is a `DECIMAL(15, 2)`, so is the result.

Comment: using case statement we cannot change the datatype right?

Comment: `CASE` cannot return 2 different data types based on its check condition. it has to return a single datatype. hence there is an implicit conversion. check this. `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 123.432 ELSE GETDATE() END`. This returns a datetime always

Comment: Of course you can explicitly use `CAST` within the `CASE` or `CAST(CASE)`

Comment: then how can I change datatype conditionally?

Comment: You can't. Each column in a result has to have a single fixed type for all rows - imagine if your `CASE` *expression* was being evaluated against multiple rows and some of those rows said `Yes` and others didn't. How would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a try and I think this could work in this case, try `sql_variant` data-type like this:

```
DECLARE @val sql_variant;
```

Answer (score 2):

- [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

You have an implicit conversion in your `CASE` statement. Basically, `c2` must have a data-type, but SQL Server doesn't know whether it's `DECIMAL(15,2)` or `BIGINT`, as both types are returned from the various branches through the `CASE` statement. The rules of data-type precedence kick in and `c2` ends up being converted to a `DECIMAL(15,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first select statement the result for c2 can only be BIGINT.
In the second statement the result can be BIGINT or DECIMAL(15,2), belongs to which branch of case statement is entered. **Since you can't have mixed types in one column** sql server automatically converts c2 to DECIMAL(15,2)

Comment: I want to change datatype conditionally. Is it possible?

Comment: In the same column? What a crime...
have a look a sqlvariant datatype if you want but i would not recommend having "dynamic datatypes" - bad programming style

Answer (score 0):

BIGINT is an integer value (it does not allow scale), try using DECIMAL or NUMERIC.
And don't give up reading [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).